# Peer Review message after edit suggestion is missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, mobile-web

In the mobile version of Stack Exchange sites, users who don't have edit privileges (or have not logged in) see a *improve this question* link. After making an edit suggestion there is no indication that the edit will be visible after peer review. The following **message**, which is displayed on the web version, **is missing from the mobile web version**:

> Thanks for your edit!
>
> This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed

Screen shots:

[image]

---

After edit suggestion, *improve this question* link goes away but peer review message is not displayed either.

[image]

---

Peer review message as displayed on the web version:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mobile site does not have all the features of the desktop version, including suggested edits. I'll investigate.

---

It was simply a bug (we already supported the same banner on the answers), Fix will be out in the next deployment.